# Newline in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

The table of contents of my document is similar to this example:

```
1 Chapter
    1.1 Section
    1.2 Section
2 Chapter
    2.1 Section
        2.1.1 Subsection
        2.1.2 Subsection
    2.2 Section
---------- page break ----------
        2.2.1 Subsection
        2.2.2 Subsection
3 Chapter
    3.1 Section
    3.2 Section
```

I want to manually move the page break one row up, before the *2.2 Section* line.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[4]}` just before that section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[4]} % <--------------
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Output with that line commented:

[image]

Comment: Of course this should be done only at the last minute, when no more text will be added to the document and the table of contents is stable.

Comment: It works :) Can you explain me the use of [4] with pagebreak?

Comment: @Andrea Of course. The optional argument (from 0 to 4) tells LaTeX how insistent the pagebreak request is. The higher the number, the more insistent the request is.