# Table of content with long entry across two pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, indexing

In my thesis, I have a section with a very long name, which must appear in its entirety in the table of content.

The title consists of three lines and, unfortunately, it is split in two different pages. Is there any way to fix this by putting the whole section title in the second page?

Thanks!

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adopt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170727/11232) given by Karl. In case if you want the section to stay in the current page as a whole, you may use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}} % here
```

Change `\baselineskip` suitably.

Code: (adopted from linked answer):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[4]} % here
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}} % here
\section{Section that has some long lines Section that has some long lines Section that has some long lines Section that has some long lines Section that has some long lines}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the `\documentclass` is a standard class you can switch to a counterpart KOMA-Script class. These classes prevent splitting of entries in lists like the table of contents automatically. The document classes `article`, `report`, and `book` can be replaced by `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, and `scrbook`, respectively.

(Because KOMA-Script uses styles for the headings that differ from the styles in the standard classes, it is advisable to load the class with the `headings=standardclasses` option if the old familiar appearance is desired.)